# Colorize text in input text with different color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to highlight text in input fields basing on a proper pattern. So I need to have the possibility to highlight a part of text by different colors. For example:

```
{pseudo}
    AB{red}CD{/red} 1234{yellow}5678{/yellow}
{/pseudo}
```

Comment: you haven't given any criteria to work with, or real html

Comment: real html: <input type="text" value="ABCD 12345678" />, make CD as red and 5678 as yellow

Comment: is this for display only?  what criteria to split text? you need to give a lot more details on behavior you want. Display only is far easier than dynamic user entry, you can't colorize inside an input tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've performed some investigation and found that such a things do with helping of textarea and  editable iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make multiple input fields that have zero border and the same background, then place those in a div that looks like an input field. Set the colors of them differently, then have some javascript that, if the box is empty, auto-set-focus to the first input field, and just automatically jump to the next one as they type.